# Catching TCP reject errors with $.ajax() and jQuery 1.4.3

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, tcp

I am writing Ajax code for a site that is stuck to jQuery 1.4.3. It happens that my Ajax call receives a TCP reject (that is ok and part of the project). Unfortunately with this jQuery version `complete` is never called. With jQuery 2 it works and `status` contains `error`. I can't update the jQuery version.

Can the code be fixed that Ajax fails due to TCP rejects will be catched?

This is a simplified part of my code that reproduces the problem. It assumes that `localhost:9999` is rejected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9999',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'script',
        complete: function(XMLHTTPRequest, status) {
            console.log(status);
        },
    });
});
```

I set up a http://jsfiddle.net/c2Yt6/ where you can test it: even with jQuery 1.6.4 is doesn't work but jQuery 2.0.2 is ok.

How to catch TCP reject errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.js

```
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
```

This part should execute in your code (add unminified and put a breakpoint there)

The problem is that the event listener function never gets executed. If I copy that code and add a line:

```
script.onerror=function(e){
  console.log("some error",e);
};
```

Then the error is detected and logged.

Looks like a bug in jQuery 1.4.3. If all you want to do is load scripts then I suggest not using jQuery but code like this:

```
function loadScript(params){
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = params.url;
  s.onload = function(){
    s.parentElement.removeChild(s);
    params.success();
  };
  s.onerror = function(){
    s.parentElement.removeChild(s);
    params.error();
  };
  document.body.appendChild(s);
};
```

Comment: I suggest passing the first argument for `onerror` to the handler because it contains the error event which contains useful information.

Comment: @dboehmer You still may need to `s.onerror = function(e){e=e||window.event;` for IE but I'm not sure.